# How to implement the drag drop option in iphone sdk in single view?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Actually i am writing a code for drag and drop option for quiz in objective-c.Basically it will jumble the letters with images and the user has to drag and drop the images and set the correct word how to do this?can u please any one send a sample for this .thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find lot of samples if you search for drag and drop images. few of them are [this](http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/iphone/examples/iphone-DoubleImageMoveasd.html) and [this](http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/10/20/iphone-programming-tutorial-using-uitouch-to-drag-an-image-around-the-screen/). Other part, correct word is set or not you need to apply your logic in that.

Comment: actually i need to drop in particular place .like drop there are 3 images like P I P .i need to drop those images into another empty uiimageviews once he drop one image into one imageview he can drag and drop the same image into another imageview also ..

Comment: @Sairam thats what I told you, rest logic you have to set. Drag and drop image functionality you can find from those tutorials.